# How to have dialogue box appear but without the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" message in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that you are able to save notes.

If a user writes some notes without saving it and tries to navigate away, the dialogue box appears alerting the user that the changes will be lost unless you save it.

The message is as follows:

"You have unsaved changes in the Notes section. Please save your changes or they will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

This scenario is fine. However there is a submit buttons on the page (that submits a form), and if the user clicks on the submit button the dialogue box appears with that same message.

In this scenario I want the same message to appear but without the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?". I don't seem to have any control over it. When the submit button is clicked, the same page appears after the form is submitted, which is why I don't want that part of the message to appear.

**How do I remove the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" part of the message?**

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    var lastClickedElement = document.activeElement;

    var submitButtonOne = document.getElementById("submitButton1");
    var submitButtonTwo = document.getElementById("submitButton2");

    if (!lastClickedElement.isEqualNode(submitButtonOne)) {

        if (lastClickedElement.isEqualNode(submitButtonTwo)) {

            if ($('#notesTextBox').val() !== currentText) {
                return 'I want this dialogue box not to contain "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"';
            }
        }

        if ($('#notesTextBox').val() !== currentText) {
            return 'You have unsaved changes in the Notes section. Please save your changes or they will be lost.';
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

> Explanation of code above - When the window.onbeforeunload is fired and the user is actually trying to navigate away from the page I want the message to appear. When the window.onbeforeunload is fired and if submitButton1 was clicked, I dont want it to do anything. When the window.onbeforeunload is fired and submitButton2 was clicked I want it display the message without the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" part.

Comment: The display of those dialog boxes is browser-dependent. I'm pretty sure you can't change how they look.

Comment: I don't think you can (in some browsers at least) - couple of years ago I think I managed to get one browser (definitely not firefox) to display exactly what I wanted and no more ... either IE or Chrome ... can't recall how it was done, as we try to make our product uniform across all browsers, so we stopped trying to remove that part of the dialog